# How to convert varchar to datetime with AM/PM in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a varchar dating field that reads as so - xx/xx/xxxx

I need to return the max as xx/xx/xxxx AM(or PM)

I can't figure out how to get it to return the max correctly while including AM/PM

I have been playing around with

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(max(STR_TO_DATE(pg_date_, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i')), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s') from cas_compliance.failedrefunds2
```

I can't get to return quite the way I need it.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1):

To convert **xx/xx/xxxx** to **xx/xx/xxxx AM(or PM)**, you can try the following:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(STR_TO_DATE(pg_date_, 
                                   '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i')
                      ), 
                  '%c/%e/%Y %r') 
FROM cas_compliance.failedrefunds2
```

**Details:**

- **%r**   Time in 12 hour AM or PM format (hh:mm:ss AM/PM)
- **%H**   Hour (00 to 23)
- **%i**   Minutes (00 to 59)
- **%c**   Numeric month name (0 to 12)
- **%e**   Day of the month as a numeric value (0 to 31)
- **%Y**   Year as a numeric, 4-digit value

Answer (score 0):

select DATE_FORMAT(now(), "%d-%m-%y %r");

Convert your date using above formating will solve problem.